# Mvvm проблемы с binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Создал свой контрол, добавил ему свойство, зарегистрировал это свойство. Но почему-то не работает binding. Что я не сделал? В чём беда?

MainWindowView:

```
<controls:MyControl Source="{Binding ListToBinding}"/>
```

CodeBehind у View:

```
DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

MyControl:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Source",
        typeof(List<object>),
        typeof(MyControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        new List<object>()));

public List<object> Source
    {
        get { return (List<object>)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }
```

MainWindowViewModel:

```
private List<object> _listToBinding;
public List<object> ListToBinding
{
    get { return _listToBinding; }
    set
    {
         _listToBinding = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("ListToBinding");
    }
}
```

Comment: Что именно не работает? Где у вас привязка контекста данных?

Comment: Покажите, как вы проставляете свойство DataContext у MyControl или контрола, его содержащего

Comment: А как работать-то должно? Естественно, что на какие-то изменения *внутри* коллекции ваш контрол не отреагирует

Comment: При изменении коллекции ListToBinding Source у контрола остаётся null :(

Comment: Дебаг показывает, что нет захода в Source.set

Comment: А его и не будет, значение устанавливается напрямую в DependencyProperty SourceProperty, а свойство Source лишь для удобства использования в коде (его можно удалить и всё будет работать по прежнему)